# Understanding JavaScript and DOM 'Interfaces'

Tags: javascript, dom

I am playing around with vanilla JavaScript and the DOM. While glancing through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), I came across the term `Interface`. As per MDN, there are various basic Interface from which other DOM elements inherit. These are [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget). I understand the concept of a `Class` in JavaScript, but what does an `Interface` mean in JavaScript? I tried playing around with the `HTMLElement` interface, but got errors.

```
const myElem1 = new HTMLElement('div')
const myElem2 = new HTMLElement('')
```

Both statements above throw the error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`. Also, an `Interface` does not seem to be a `Class`. Consider this code:

```
const elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
const height = elmnt.clientHeight
```

`clientHeight` is a property on the Interface `Element`, as per MDN. So if `Element` was a class, `clientHeight` should have been on `Element.prototype.clientHeight`, and not on `Element.clientHeight`.

Is it possible to use these Interfaces in our JavaScript program? If so, what's the correct way, and what are some use cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface is a general term in OO-programming.

It is *like* a class in that it defines features that must appear on an object, but you can't use it directly. Instead you must use a class which implements it.

So you can't create an instance of HTMLElement, but since Div *implements* HTMLElement and Span *implements* HTMLElement you can create an instance of Div *or* Span and either will satisfy a requirement to have an HTMLElement.

Interfaces are generally used to avoid problems in multiple inheritance. A class can implement multiple interfaces which have overlapping requirements (say both interfaces require a `Dance` method) whereas if it *extended* two classes which had a `Dance` method you'd need to pick which of the two parent classes to take `Dance` from an which to ignore).

---

Note that JavaScript has no Interface language feature (although [TypeScript does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)). The term is just used in the DOM documentation as it is written in general OO terms and not JavaScript specific terms.

Comment: Correction: JavaScript does have inheritance, and these interfaces are not just used in the documentation. You can do something like `document.createElement('div') instanceof HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev — That was a typo. I meant interface.

Comment: @Dexygen — Mixins are a common way to implement the features required by an interface in general. The type checking won't be supported though, not even the limited level provided by `instanceof`.

Comment: If you have something like:

```js
const divElement = document.createElement('div');
if (divElement instanceof HTMLElement) {
    console.log('rootElement is HTMLElement')
}
```

and hover in HTMLElement in VSCode it shows a weird implementation

```js
var HTMLDivElement: {
    new (): HTMLDivElement;
    prototype: HTMLDivElement;
}
```
which is not a JS code. So it seems to create an interface but I'm cofused about how it does

Comment: @RayonNunes — I've really unclear what you are trying to say in your comment on a two year old question, but it looks like it should be [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and fleshed out to be clearer as per the guidelines here: [ask]